# DataGrid/GridView will not render THeader and TBody

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm using a GridView and DataGrid.  To use some JQuery I'm trying to get to work it needs to render the THeader and TBody.  **How do I force the DataGrid and GridView to render these elements?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out: http://www.webpronews.com/expertarticles/2007/01/25/aspnet-make-gridview-control-accessible

Comment: *sigh* asp.net webforms strikes again.  I really wish I didn't have to write code to manipulate the default markup...thanks for the link!